# Guardar salida de terminal python en fichero .txt

Tags: python, txt, spyder, stdout

Estoy tratando de guardar la salida de la terminal python en un fichero .txt
Lo he logrado realizando la siguiente instrucción directamente desde la terminal bash (funciona a la perfección):

`python test.py &> out.txt`

El problema que tengo es que he de llamar a dos funciones distintas y tengo que generar dos ficheros *.txt* distintos, por lo que al hacerlo como he explicado anteriormente he de ejecutar dos veces el comando, una para cada función. La función `main` donde llamo a a las funciones que generan el output en la terminal es:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  image = np.random.random((8, 8, 1)).astype(np.float32)
  filter = np.random.random((4, 4, 1)).astype(np.float32)
  image = tf_conv2d.convolution2d(image, filter)
  input = tf_conv2d.pad(image.reshape(np.prod(image.shape), 1), BS)

  # Para guardar en un String toda la salida de la terminal
  old_stdout = sys.stdout
  result = StringIO()
  sys.stdout = result

  # Aquí quiero que se genere el fichero reference.txt con el output que 
  # genera la función reference_test(A, B, BS)
  reference_test(filter, input, BS)

  # Se coge la salida y se guarda en un String para después volcar en el fichero .txt
  sys.stdout = old_stdout
  result_string = result.getvalue()

  # Aquí quiero que se genere el fichero building.txt con el output que 
  # genera la función building_test(A, B, BS)
  building_test(filter, input, BS)
```

La ejecución del fichero con el programa principal `main` lo ejecuto desde el IDE Spyder. En el mismo fichero se encuentran las dos funciones que quiero ejecutar y guardar su salida. La salida que se *printea* en la terminal no viene de Python si no de un fichero OpenCL ejecutado a través de pyOpenCL.

Comment: [esta otra respuesta: Redirect output to two files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183820/13636459) parece ser bastante útil para este tipo de casos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado una solución que satisface los requerimientos con muy poco código, solo dos o tres líneas. Funciona a la perfección. Se trata a través del paquete *wurlitzer* --> https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer

Ejemplo de código:

```
from wurlitzer import pipes

with pipes() as (out, err):
    # Se llama a la función en C++ (OpenCL en este caso)
    fpga_ref = conv2d.Matmul(H_ans, fpga_mtx, s_mask_ans.astype(np.int32), 1, 1, (H_h, H_w))

# Se almacena la salida en la variable deseada como un string
stdout = out.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ello podrías utilizar el módulo de python *sys* y redirigir el stdout a tu fichero deseado.

Para tu código, sería similar a esto:

```
import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        image = np.random.random((8, 8, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        filter = np.random.random((4, 4, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        image = tf_conv2d.convolution2d(image, filter)
        input = tf_conv2d.pad(image.reshape(np.prod(image.shape), 1), BS)

        original_stdout = sys.stdout

        # Aquí quiero que se genere el fichero reference.txt con el output que 
        # genera la función reference_test(A, B, BS)
        sys.stdout = open('reference.txt', 'w')
        reference_test(filter, input, BS)

        # Aquí quiero que se genere el fichero building.txt con el output que 
        # genera la función building_test(A, B, BS)
        sys.stdout = open('building.txt', 'w')        
        building_test(filter, input, BS)

        # Lo devolvemos al original.
        sys.stdout = original
        '''
        ¿Sería posible realizar esto mediante Popen?? Al hacerlo así me da 
        error de que no encuentra el fichero

        cmd_reference = "-c import test; test.reference_test(filer, input, BS)   &> outs/ref.txt"
        subprocess.Popen(cmd_reference)
        '''
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por la rápida respuesta. Se me ha olvidado comentar que la salida de la terminal no me viene de ninguna instrucción print() de python, si no de una instrucción printf() de el fichero OpenCL que ejecuto mediante pyOpenCL, por lo que en el fichero que se genera solo me aparece el output de los print() de python... ¿alguna idea? Gacias!

Comment: Sí. Guarda la salida del fichero OpenCL en un string e imprímela con un print desde el fichero python que ejecutas.

Comment: Pues no, sigue dando la misma salida. He editado el código de la pregunta con los cambios pertinentes y el resultado es similar a lo realizado con el código de tu respuesta.

Comment: Después de sys.stdout = old_stdout
  result_string = result.getvalue() tienes que volver a redirigir la salida.

Comment: Hola. He publicado una solución que funciona a la perfección. Estuve siguiendo tus indicaciones pero no lo conseguí. Por lo que he podido leer, no es tan fácil redirigir el stdout de funciones de C/C++ en python a una variable. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma secilla de hacerlo es usando la instrucción `print()`, redirigiendo la salida al fichero que desees. Puede ser *.txt, *.dat, o la extensión que quieras, siempre que lo que envíes sean caracteres de texto.

```
with open('archivo.txt', mode='w') as file_object:
    print('Cadena a imprimir', file=file_object)
```

No intente usar `print()` para escribir datos binarios, ya que solo es adecuado para texto. Si necesita hacerlo, simplemente llame al archivo binario con `write()` directamente:

```
with open('file.dat', 'wb') as file_object:
    file_object.write(bytes(4))
    file_object.write(b'\xff')
```

Si desea escribir bytes sin procesar en la salida estándar, esto también fallará porque `sys.stdout` debe ser un flujo de caracteres:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(bytes(4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

En su lugar, debe profundizar para obtener un control del flujo de bytes subyacente:

```
import sys
num_bytes_written = sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x41\x0a')
A
```

Esto imprime una letra mayúscula `A` y un carácter de nueva línea `\n`,
que corresponden a valores decimales de 65 y 10 en ASCII, sin embargo, están codificados usando notación hexadecimal en el literal de bytes.